# Turn Radio buttons to star rating using Elementor page builder

Tags: css, forms, radio-button, elementor

I am trying to convert all the radio buttons on a form i made using the elementor page builder to a star rating option.

I have tried using this CSS https://codeconvey.com/css-star-rating-radio-buttons/
replaceing .rating with .elementor-field-subgroup - with no effect.

any ideas i can use?

Update :

i tried this CSS& Jscript :

```
.elementor-field-group-stars label:after {font-family:eicons; content:"\e933"; color:gold}
.elementor-field-group-stars:hover label:after {content:"\e934"!important;}
.elementor-field-group-stars .elementor-field-option:hover ~ .elementor-field-option > label:after {content:"\e933"!important;}
.elementor-field-group-stars.selected label:after {content:"\e934";}
.elementor-field-group-stars.selected .elementor-field-option.active ~ .elementor-field-option label:after {content:"\e933"}
.elementor-field-group-stars input {display:none!important}
.elementor-field-group-stars label {color:transparent}
.elementor-field-group-stars .elementor-field-option {padding:0!important}


$('.elementor-field-group-stars input').click(function() {
               if($('.elementor-field-group-stars input').is(':checked'))  {
                   $(".elementor-field-group-stars").addClass("selected");
                   $(".elementor-field-option").removeClass("active");
                   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
}
});
```

which works for one radio button at a time - and not for all the radio buttons on page - which is close - but not there yet

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can directly change radio buttons to stars using Elementor but since you mentioned using it Elementor has a premade star rating widget that you can use. From personal experience I can say that it's working pretty well and you can design it to fit your liking.

Here is a link to YouTube where you can see more:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J6LcRzknTc&feature=emb_title

Comment: hi, 
i need a star rating for users to answer a satisfaction survey, not to display stars on screen. thats why i need to use the form/

Comment: Then perhaps something like this would help you.